# Selenium get all options in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, selenium

I see similar question, but this is different than those. The other questions show a loop iterating over the options. This question is much simpler.

Selenium documentation tells of a getOptions() method. That seems like exactly what I want, but I get an error every time I use it.

I have a dropdown that I have an ID for.
I want an array of the options inside of the dropdown.

here is an example of code

```
const sampleDropdown = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('id-of-dropdown')));
```

this gives the correct dropdown and inside of the "inspect" I can see the options. However, a simple append .getOptions() does not work. It seems like this should? Suggestions?

basically this

```
const sampleDropdown = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('id-of-dropdown'))).getOptions();
console.log(sampleDropdown);
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that represents the dropdown you are wanting to automate? Selenium's built-in `getOptions()` method only works with a specific type of HTML dropdown element - that's why you are seeing so many solutions with loops iterating over options. And - when you say `getOptions()` does not work, what exactly do you mean? `sampleDropdown` is null?

Comment: .getOptions() is not a function. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment from above into an answer - `getOptions()` is valid on a `Select` object, not a `WebElement` - from your example, you would need to wrap your `driver.wait(...)` function in a `new Select` statement as such:

```
Select sampleDropdown = new Select(driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('id-of-dropdown'))));

List<WebElement> options = sampleDropdown.getOptions();

console.log(options);
```